# How to switch between dedicated NVIDIA gpu and integrated AMD gpu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu, amd-processor

i was wondering how to switch between those two. I have finally installed drivers for NVIDIA and made it work but I cant switch it to integrated to save battery, in nvidia-settings or through sudo prime-select intel, it selects the profile, which is grey and cannot be normally selected through GUI, but the laptop still uses NVIDIA gpu. Any tips?